# Shopware6 Filesystem unexpected behaviour with S3 config

Tags: amazon-s3, shopware6

following https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/infrastructure/filesystem.html I configured an AWS S3 bucket to work with my shopware6 installation like this

```
shopware:
    filesystem:
      public:
        url: "https://%env(AWS_BUCKET)%.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"
        type: "amazon-s3"
        config:
            bucket: "%env(AWS_BUCKET)%"
            region: "%env(AWS_REGION)%"
            endpoint: "%env(AWS_BUCKET_ENDPOINT)%"
            credentials:
              key: "%env(AWS_ACCESS_KEY)%"
              secret: "%env(AWS_ACCESS_SECRET)%"
            root: ""
            options:
              visibility: "public"
      theme:
        url: "https://%env(AWS_BUCKET)%.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"
        type: "amazon-s3"
        config:
            bucket: "%env(AWS_BUCKET)%"
            region: "%env(AWS_REGION)%"
            endpoint: "%env(AWS_BUCKET_ENDPOINT)%"
            credentials:
              key: "%env(AWS_ACCESS_KEY)%"
              secret: "%env(AWS_ACCESS_SECRET)%"
            root: ""
            options:
              visibility: "public"
#      asset:
#        url: "https://%env(AWS_BUCKET)%.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"
#        type: "amazon-s3"
#        config:
#            bucket: "%env(AWS_BUCKET)%"
#            region: "%env(AWS_REGION)%"
#            endpoint: "%env(AWS_BUCKET_ENDPOINT)%"
#            credentials:
#              key: "%env(AWS_ACCESS_KEY)%"
#              secret: "%env(AWS_ACCESS_SECRET)%"
#            root: ""
#            options:
#              visibility: "public"
      sitemap:
        url: "https://%env(AWS_BUCKET)%.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"
        type: "amazon-s3"
        config:
            bucket: "%env(AWS_BUCKET)%"
            region: "%env(AWS_REGION)%"
            endpoint: "%env(AWS_BUCKET_ENDPOINT)%"
            credentials:
              key: "%env(AWS_ACCESS_KEY)%"
              secret: "%env(AWS_ACCESS_SECRET)%"
            root: ""
            options:
              visibility: "public"
```

So as you can see - I commented out the "asset"-part. Expected behaviour is that now the files for bundles where stored local in public/bundles. But if I execute

```
bin/console assets:install
```

The files for bundles where still stored in the s3 bucket. The same unwanted behaviour I noticed if I comment out the "theme" part.
Why? And how can I prevent this?
(Clearing cache dosn't changed that behaviour)